# Is it possible to open multiple instances or split view of chrome developer tools tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug code at the same time as I see what is being sent on the network tab without having to go back and forth between the **Network tab** and **Sources tab**. Is there a way to do this as of chrome Version 52.0.2743.82 or Version 54.0.2810.2 canary?

I know that it is possible to log http request in the console which can be visible with other tabs open but I want the actuall networks tab if possible..

Thank you in advance

Comment: This would be amazingly useful!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is now possible in Chrome 87. Right click Network in the menu and select "Move to bottom"

[image: Right click Network]

and it will do this

[image: Move any Tab Under other tabs]

Comment: They made it so intuitive.....I know I'm not supposed to thank you but, thanks man, you're the real MVP.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to have console, network and source opened all at the same time?

Comment: @BanAnanas You can have network open with the console at the bottom, but if you move Sources to the bottom, you have to choose between Console and Sources. Not sure if there is another way to do that.

Comment: this is so nice

Comment: How have I only just found this out now! ty!

Answer (score 19):

You can view 'Quick source' while viewing the Network panel (or the other main panels) at the same. This will allow you to view the source and add breakpoints.

However, it's **not possible to step through code using the debugging in the split view**. Chrome will automatically switch to the Sources tab if you use the shortcuts.

It's also not possible to have an extension running a separate instance of the debugger as the [Chrome Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) doesn't allow simultaneous clients to be connected.

I will open up a discussion with other Chromium contributors into the feasibility of sharing the debugging controls in the split view. I don't know whether it will or can be done easily. I suspect it's a fair amount of work.

If you would like to set up the split view, as it's useful anyway, go to overflow menu on the right side and select 'More Tools' and then select 'Show console'. This makes sure the panel loads below the main one.

[image: Show console]

On the left side of the panel that shows, click the overflow menu and select 'Quick source'.

[image: Quick Source]

You will now see a small Sources panel.

[image: Quick Source]

Comment: Ah, that's awesome! Somehow I thought quick source was just for viewing.

Comment: @mattzeunert You can set breakpoints in it, but when you use the debugger controls (F10 etc), it switches you back to the Sources tab. It would be great if you could step through without it switching tab.

Comment: @Gideon, thanks for the reply! I really need the possibility to step through the code and see the networks tab at the same time.. :(

Comment: @54N1 Unfortunately, it's not possible to have the debugging controls present in the Network tab.

Comment: "I will open up a discussion with other Chromium contributors..." @GideonPyzer -- Is there somewhere where we can up-vote the request for this? It would be amazingly useful when you're debugging code that sends out network requests.

Comment: It's already possible in modern Chrome we can open a second devtools via `chrome://inspect` page.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was referred here from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635541/is-it-possible-to-open-multiple-instances-or-split-view-of-chrome-developer-tool) question, I'll answer here.

In my scenario I need to be able to work on two different source files (under DevTools->Sources) simultaneously, for instance an *html* and a *css* file.

My workaround was to work on two separate tabs.
Right click one of them and click 'Open in new tab'.

[image]

When the new tab is open press F12 to open DevTools, and dock the two editors side by side (Focus on one and pressing <kbd>⊞</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> then leftwards on the other one).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your link points back to this same question; was that intentional, or is there another related question you meant to reference? Nice workaround, btw!