# How do I put Network panel and Sources panel together, side by side?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm putting breakpoints and trace the code line by line.
In the meantime, I also need to check the network status.
How do I put these two panels together instead of switching these two panels back and forth?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open multiple instances or split view of chrome developer tools tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635541/is-it-possible-to-open-multiple-instances-or-split-view-of-chrome-developer-tool)

Comment: Go to `chrome://inspect` and open a second devtools instance for the same page, then arrange the tabs/windows to your liking.